# GCP + Terraform : Service account access is granted to a user at project level

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-iam, tfsec

I have an issue when trying to execute this terraform file on GCP.

```
Results #1-2 MEDIUM Service account access is granted to a user at project level. (2 similar results)
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
iam.tf Line 18
───────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   9  │ resource "google_project_iam_member" "permissions" {
  10  │   for_each = toset([
  11  │     "logging.logWriter",
  12  │     "errorreporting.writer",
  13  │     "iam.serviceAccountUser",
  14  │     "iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator",
  15  │     "workflows.invoker"
  16  │   ])
  17  │   provider = google-beta
  18  │   role     = "roles/${each.key}"
  19  │   member   = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.default.email}"
  20  │ }
───────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 Individual Causes
 - /Users/oussamafathallah/git/btdp/modules/00-oauth2-relay/iac/iam.tf:9-20 (google_project_iam_member.permissions)
 - /Users/oussamafathallah/git/btdp/modules/00-oauth2-relay/iac/iam.tf:9-20 (google_project_iam_member.permissions)
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
         ID google-iam-no-project-level-service-account-impersonation
     Impact Privilege escalation, impersonation of any/all services
 Resolution Provide access at the service-level instead of project-level, if required

 More Information
 - https://aquasecurity.github.io/tfsec/v1.0.2/checks/google/iam/no-project-level-service-account-impersonation/
 - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam
```

Can you help me on this issue please. I'm new to gcp and terraform. Thank you !

Comment: With which credential are your running the TF script? What the permissions of that credential? Can you show the provider definition?

Comment: i dont know. I just executed the command "make all" (makerfile).

Comment: I don't know too!! Go deeper in the makefile to find the answer. I can't help from there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Granting this role **"iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"** causes the warning.

That role allows users to use a service account for **Privilege Escalation**

[Protecting against privilege-escalation threats](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-securing-service-accounts#privilege-escalations)

Comment: it's also the role "iam.serviceAccountUser" that allows users to impersonate all service accounts in the projet.